# Authentication scenario with optional login

Tags: node.js, angular, express, authentication

I'm using express and angular 5
so normally you make authorization based on user registration,
what i simple need to do is make the website open with optional login for more features but also need to secure my API routes so they are not accessible from outside the app.
Example:

when an action in the app make a get request from an endpoint, the backend should authorize the request if it comes from the app, but block it if the someone tried to make a request from something like postman.

so app makes request to `GET https://api.sample.com`data returns
if someone tries to `GET https://api.sample.com` from outside it should return unauthorized or error message

Comment: Generally, people add an authorization token to the header of requests to verify that credentials were used to create a token. To block postman you can restrict the origin to only come the same domain, but it's easy to fake an origin.

Comment: i know but all those has kind of work arounds, i was thinking that maybe there is a strategy where you can authenticate the app itself once it loads rather than authenticating a user, but i may not aware of how to properly describe it or search for it

Comment: Security should be in the back-end and your API should be secure no matter what client uses it. That's how your protect yourself from harm, because anyone can ghost your Angular application easily.

Comment: that's my question i don't want any client to be able to consume my services, how would you restrict access without credentials

Comment: Don't put your service on the *open and public* internet.